# I keep getting a UnicodeDecodeError when trying to pull lines from multiple ascii files into a single file. How can I resolve this?

Tags: python, unicode, concatenation, ascii

The files I am working with are .ASC files, each represents an analysis of a sample on a mass spectrometer. The same isotopes were measured in each sample and therefore the files have common headers. The goal of this code is to pull the lines of text which contain the common headers and the counts per second (cps) data from all of the .ASC files in a given folder and to compile it into a single file.

I have searched around and I believe my code is along the right lines, but I keep getting encoding errors. I have tried specifying the encoding wherever I call 'open('and I have tried using ascii as the encoding type and utf-8, but still errors.

Below are the error messages I received:

**Without specifying encoding:** UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1010: character maps to undefined>

**ascii: UnicodeDecodeError:** 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 148: ordinal not in range(128)

**utf-8: UnicodeDecodeError:** 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 148: invalid continuation byte

I am very inexperienced with coding so if you notice anything idiotic in the code, let me know.

```
filepath = open("insert_filepath_here")

output_lst = []
def process_file(filepath):
    interesting_keys = (
    'Li7(LR)',
    'Be9(LR)',
    'Na23(LR)',
    'Rb85(LR)',
    'Sr88(LR)',
    'Y89(LR)',
    'Zr90(LR)',
    'Nb93(LR)',
    'Mo95(LR)',
    'Cd111(LR)',
    'In115(LR)',
    'Sn118(LR)',
    'Cs13(LR)',
    'Ba137(LR)',
    'La139(LR)',
    'Ce140(LR)',
    'Pr141(LR)',
    'Nd146(LR)',
    'Sm147(LR)',
    'Eu153(LR)',
    'Gd157(LR)',
    'Tb159(LR)',
    'Dy163(LR)',
    'Ho165(LR)',
    'Er166(LR)',
    'Tm169(LR)',
    'Yb172(LR)',
    'Lu175(LR)',
    'Hf178(LR)',
    'Ta181(LR)',
    'W182(LR)',
    'Tl205(LR)',
    'Pb208(LR)',
    'Bi209(LR)',
    'Th232(LR)',
    'U238(LR)',
    'Mg24(MR)',
    'Al27(MR)',
    'Si28(MR)',
    'Ca44(MR)',
    'Sc45(MR)',
    'Ti47(MR)',
    'V51(MR)',
    'Cr52(MR)',
    'Mn55(MR)',
    'Fe56(MR)',
    'Co59(MR)',
    'Ni60(MR)',
    'Cu63(MR)',
    'Zn66(MR)',
    'Ga69(MR)',
    'K39(HR)'
    )

with open(filepath) as fh:
    content = fh.readlines()
    for line in content:
        line = line.strip()
        if ":" in line:
            key, _ = line.split(":",1)
            if key.strip() in interesting_keys:
                output_lst.append(line)

def write_output_data():
    if output_lst:
        with open(output_file, "w") as fh:
            fh.write("\n".join(output_lst))
            print("See", output_file)
        
def process_files():
    for filepath in os.listdir(input_dir):
        process_file(os.path.join(input_dir, filepath))
    
write_output_data()

process_files()
```

Comment: Sounds like the input isn't in either of those encodings, which most likely means it's either one of the common 8-bit encodings (the ISO-8859-* family is a common one) or it's not plain text at all (i.e. it has some binary data in there that isn't in "an encoding" at all). In ISO-8859-1, for example 0xC4 is `Ä` (Umlaut A, A with diaeresis).

Comment: can't tell without knowing what is in that file. but you can try "latin1" encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This has returned no errors and now the code will parse and return no errors. However, I get not output file from running the code.

Comment: You call `write_output_data` **before** `process_files`. That seems the wrong way around.